# Finitely additive measure over $\mathbb{N}$, under AD.

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Under the axiom of choice, there are lots of non-trivial (that is, a measure vanishes every finite set) finitely-additive measures over $\mathbb{N}$: for example, ultrafilters over $\mathbb{N}$ or measures occur in [other answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/95959/48041). However, as far as I know, $\mathsf{AD}$ proves every ultrafilter is $\aleph_1$-complete and hence every ultrafilter over $\mathbb{N}$ is principal.

My question is: does the same result hold for (real-valued) measures? That is, I wonder whether $\mathsf{AD}$ proves every finitely-additive measure is $\sigma$-additive. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems everyone is assuming the measure is bounded. Do you know what happens when we drop that assumption?

Comment: @Lxm You can reproduce bof's proof by taking any infinite subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\mu(X)<\infty$ and restricting $\mu$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: I meant to say an unbounded finitely additive signed measure...so that we don't have monotonicity

Comment: @Lxm I am not familiar with unbounded signed measure, and so I do not know in that case.

Comment: As Asaf says bounded signed measures correspond to functionals on $\ell^\infty$, so consistently they are just $\ell^1$, and this really doesn't use the full power of AD. But that's for bounded measures, so I wonder what about unbounded ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you define a "nontrivial" finitely additive measure over $\mathbb N.$ I will assume that it's a finitely additive set function $\mu:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to[0,1]$ such that $\mu(\mathbb N)=1$ and $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb N.$ I will show how to construct an undetermined game from such a measure $\mu.$

Consider an infinitely long game where two players, White and Black, take turns choosing finite sets $W_1,B_1,W_2,B_2,\dots$ of previously unchosen elements of $\mathbb N;$ White goes first, but that won't matter. Let $W=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}W_n,$ the set of numbers chosen by White, and let $B=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n,$ the set of numbers chosen by Black. The payoff is that Black wins if $\mu(B)\ge\frac25,$ while White wins if $\mu(B)\lt\frac25.$ As there are countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb N,$ this is equivalent to a game where the players choose natural numbers. I claim that neither player has a winning strategy, contrary to AD.

Suppose White has a winning strategy, i.e., a strategy which guarantees that $\mu(B)\lt\frac25.$ A simple modification (choose one more number at each turn, so as to make sure that all numbers are eventually chosen) gives White a strategy which guarantees that $\mu(W)\gt\frac35.$ However, since finite sets have measure zero, the first move confers no advantage; Black could adopt the same strategy and thereby guarantee that $\mu(B)\gt\frac35.$ Since $\mu(W)+\mu(B)\gt\frac65$ is impossible, White has no winning strategy.

Suppose Black has a winning strategy, which guarantees that $\mu(B)\ge\frac25.$ Now consider a game played by three players, Red, Green, and Yellow, who take turns choosing disjoint finite sets $R_1,G_1,Y_1,R_2,G_2,Y_2,\dots,$ and let $R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}R_n$ be the set of numbers chosen by Red, $G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}G_n$ the set of numbers chosen by Green, and $Y=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}Y_n$ the set of numbers chosen by Yellow. If each player imagines that he is playing Black (and using the winning strategy) in a two-person game, with his two adversaries together playing White, then the game will end up with $\mu(R)+\mu(G)+\mu(Y)\ge\frac65.$ This absurdity shows that Black has no winning strategy.

Comment: Nice trick. White still uses the original strategy, imagining the extra numbers she is playing are actually part of the sets played by Black.

Comment: Or White can just ignore the extra numbers, computing the strategic response to the sets actually chosen by Black, and then adding extra numbers to fill in the gaps.,

Answer (score 7):

You can show that every finitely additive measure on $\Bbb N$ corresponds to a continuous functional on $\ell^\infty$ which is not induced by a sequence in $\ell^1$.

Consequently, such a measure shows there is a set without the Baire property. This, of course, contradicts $\sf AD$.

You can find the proof in Schechter's Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations.

Comment: You can also find the proof in the note I wrote about Zorn's lemma in functional analysis, which you can find on my homepage.

Comment: Existence of such continuous functional is a motivation of my question! I will read your posts and accept the answer, but time does not allow me to read it now. I will check it at night.

Comment: @bof: It is my special nickname for Rene-Louis Baire. Specifically, that's how my phone likes to write his name.

Comment: @Hanul: You should accept the other answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it points out the motivation of my question, but I agree with your comment. bof's proof is interesting and easy to understand, so I follow your suggestion :)